# how to capture all the id's if the div's which are inside a specific div and add them in a collection through JQuery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below HTML DOM:

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
<div class="item active" id="287"></div>
<div class="item" id="288"></div>
<div class="item" id="451"></div>
<div class="item" id="452"></div>
</div>
```

Now, using JQuery I want to create a collection which should look like:

```
var forms= {
    287:"0",
    288:"0",
    451:"0",
    452:"0"
};
```

Basically, I would like to update this collection later, making specific property values as "1" or something like this.
Any help will be highly appretiated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jQuery, you can select a node's [children](https://api.jquery.com/children/) and loop through them with [each](https://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
var forms = {};
$('.carousel-inner').children().each(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if (id) {
        forms[id] = "0";
    }
});
```

You can also filter which children you want to select: by tag `.children('div')` or by class `.children('.item')`

Answer (score 0):

See this:

```
var container = document.querySelector('.carousel-inner'),
    objectWithIds = {};

for (var i = 0; i < container.children.length; i++){
    if (container.children[i].id){
        objectWithIds[container.children[i].id] = "0"
    }
}

console.log(objectWithIds)
```

If you want only the `DIV` tags, change the `if statement` to `container.children[i].id && container.children[i].tagName == "DIV"`